# cloth and collision problem

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, collision

problem:
I want to make it looks like the cup is passing through the curtain but it seems like the curtain are attached to the cup??

I am using cloth modifier for my curtain and collision modifier for my cup.

question:
How can I prevent the cloth from the collision?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

update: turns out i just have to scale all of my objects, i don't really know the reasons behind of it but it works after i scale it up

Comment: It is important to use realistic scale and properties for the simulations - otherwise the phsyics can produce expected results. Always make sure you're working to correct scale and units, always 'apply scale' to all your meshes, check your collision settings (and reduce the thresholds if things are behaving oddly) and consider increasing the simulation step size and quality.